# How did Hugh Crain avoid financial ruin?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-haunting-of-hill-house

[Contains spoilers of the first episode, but I've tried to obscure details learned in later episodes.]

In Netflix's *The Haunting of Hill House*, the Crain family bought Hill House in the 1980s, hoping the renovate it over a summer and then flip it.  They end up abandoning the house while on the verge of financial ruin.

> When the mold problem is discovered, Hugh tries to deal with it himself and tells his son that there's not enough money left to hire more people.

In 2018, the house is unoccupied and Mr. & Mrs. Dudley still maintain it.

> We eventually learn that Hugh had promised the Dudleys he would not resell the house and he would keep the Dudleys on as caretakers.

Even if Aunt Janet took on all the expenses of raising the kids, mortgage payments, property tax, and salaries add up.  How did Hugh afford all that in the first months and years after they left the house?

If he had declared bankruptcy or just defaulted on the mortgage, the bank would have foreclosed. If he had failed to make property tax payments, the state would have garnished his wages (assuming he got another job) or put a lien against the house.

With the outstanding debt, it seems unlikely he could have gotten more financing to continue flipping houses.  Steve's earnings as an author covered a lot of expenses for the family, but those royalties would have been years out.

Did I miss something about a life insurance policy on Olivia (his wife) or the Dudleys offering their life savings?  Did he sell off antiques from the house?  Did Aunt Janet bail him out?